# Cleanly respawning xmobar when reload xmonad

Tags: xmonad

This is just a small annoyance, but I've made the XMonad configuration file load xmobar using this code:

```
xmproc <- spawnPipe "/use/bin/xmobar ~/.xmobarrc"
```

It works well, but it spawn a new xmobar process every time XMonad is reloaded. I wonder if there's an easy way to kill the old one?

**update**: As suggested by entropo, I've created a bash script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

for PID in `pgrep xmobar`; do
    kill ${PID} > /dev/null &
done

/usr/bin/xmobar &
```

and call that script from XMonad configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not xmonad specific, but you could launch xmobar through a shell script that checks for an existing xmobar process.  See, e.g., http://bash.cyberciti.biz/web-server/restart-apache2-httpd-shell-script/

Answer (score 17):

If you have a shell script to start XMobar then you are 'doing it wrong'. You should be starting xmobar using the correct Haskell functions in the xmonad.hs config source file. Take a look at my configs main function:

```
-- put it all together
main = do
    nScreens <- countScreens    -- just in case you are on a laptop like me count the screens so that you can go
    xmonad =<< xmobar myBaseConfig
      { modMask = myModMask
      , workspaces = withScreens nScreens myWorkspaces
      , layoutHook = myLayoutHook nScreens
      , manageHook = myManageHook
      , borderWidth = myBorderWidth
      , normalBorderColor = myNormalBorderColor
      , focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor
      , keys = myKeys
      , mouseBindings = myMouseBindings
      , logHook = myLogHook
      }
    where
        myLogHook = dynamicLogXinerama

myBaseConfig = gnomeConfig
```

The salient line is this one:

```
xmonad =<< xmobar myBaseConfig
```

That runs xmobar as it should be run, even when you reload xmonad. You get the 'xmobar' function from the statement:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog (xmobar)
```

Which in turn comes from the [xmonad-contrib package](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#v:xmobar).

So you see, most things that you want to do with XMonad are already a solved problem, you just have to know where to look. Basically, just ditch your script and use that instead. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I've found the `spawnPipe` code on the XMonad website, it's really not easy to know where to look! But in the end, I prefer the technique I'm using as it is cleaner, using `DynamicLog` didn't kill the old process in my tests. I really like XMonad, but Haskell is not a good configuration language.

Comment: Okay, whatever works for you is good in the end. But I think you are thinking about it wrong. You do not configure XMonad: you extend it. Haskell the prefect fit for extension.

Comment: For me this is creating 2 new processes each time I reload xmonad. Using spawnPipe creates 2 additional processes. ps -ax returns: "/bin/sh -c  /.cabal/bin/xmobar ~/.xmobarrc:", "/bin/sh -c xmobar", "~/.cabal/bin/xmonad ~/.xmobarrc" and "xmobar".

Comment: Reinstalling both fixed the issue in my commend above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `spawnPipe` will fork a process in a new thread. If you want to make `spawnPipe` create a child process instead (one that closes when the main process does), I'm afraid you'll have to write your own `spawnPipe` function.

Comment: `XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog.xmobar` is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#xmobar) in terms of `spawnPipe`...

Comment: I tried n solutions already and none fixed the problem, the previous xmobar process isn't killed. The only way I could manage that was spawning a `killall "xmobar"` command.

Comment: An important point which was not mentioned is that you must have `Run StdinReader` (or `Run UnsafeStdinReader`) in your xmobar config. The `StdinReader` implementation makes xmobar exit when it sees EOF on its stdin, which happens when xmonad closes its end of pipe during the restart.